# Why are some old images downloaded from the web always sorted under "Today" in Gallery?

Tags: gallery, images

When I open the gallery and sort by Time, there is always a section "Today", and it has several images I downloaded from the web...... months ago.

That's literally it. Why are old images showing under "Today"? There are other images I got from the web that are actually correctly sorted in older sections. But under "Today" I got around 20 web images that have been sitting there for months.

One thing I noticed is that this doesn't happen with photos taken with the phone. Such photos are always correctly sorted. So it's something with web images.

Android 5.0, Galaxy S5.

Comment: I don't have S5 so I would like to know: is the problem specific to the default Gallery or with any Gallery app like [Piktures](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.diune.pictures&hl=en)?

Comment: @Firelord interesting! I installed Piktures and the same photos are at the top when I sort it by date! Not sure what's wrong with those images.

Comment: Could you please check for surety the time-stamp on those images, using your file explorer?

Comment: @Firelord in the Gallery, I use "details" on the images, and I discovered that the year is set to something like 4235 or something high like that. This explains the sorting problem. However, I don't understand how could that have happened and, more importantly: how to fix it without actually deleting the images.

Comment: 1) Which OS in your PC are you using? 2) Is the device rooted? See if [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.pogsoftwares.filetimestamp) helps in your case.

Comment: @Firelord     1) Mac OSX     2) No it isn't

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into some **EXIF** editors to edit the metadata of those images (specifically the time). I can't name any great editors in particular, but there are plenty of apps and programs available as I looked through. If I find any good ones, I'll be sure to tell you the names of them. Best of luck!

Comment: Here's one that seems to work great, and allows multiple photos to be edited at a time: [Photo exif editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.xnano.android.photoexifeditor)

Answer (score 0):

Ok first, if the photos already have a wrong timestamp, there's nothing your phone is doing wrong. You just need to readjust the time stamps. Do this easily by using any photo editor on your phone or pc and open them and save them with a different name or as is. It will change the time to your specific machine, phone or pc time, do it with every photo and then delete the previous one and add these to your gallery and let it sync again. It will correct itself after that.